# How can I avoid widening of object property in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

it seems I can't get the specific key type of object.

example:

```
function defineProps<T extends string>(name: T) {
  return { [name]: undefined } as const;
}

const result = defineProps('a');
// I expect { a: undefined } 
// but get { [x:string]: undefined }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a to Record<T, undefined>. I don't think there is another way.

```
function defineProps<T extends string>(name: T) {
  return { [name]: undefined } as Record<T, undefined>;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKbBmVAFATnABwGcAeAFUVQA8pUxkjEipdMBzAPgAowBDAW1QAuRGQCUiAN4BYAFCJEuVFBC4kkxAG0+ggLojwaDFmSIAvol6MASqghxcycgBpEh9JlTIOAbjlm5OXswZkVUIhAAGyhEAF4UDyw8QiIuAHJeNLEfIA)

In all fairness this isn't 100% type safe if you initialize to something beside  `undefined`. `name` could be a union such as `'a' | 'b'`, so the resulting type will be `{ a: undefined, b: undefined }` even though you are initializing only one of those properties (either `a` or `b` depending on what is actually in `name`)

Comment: thanks for your answer, that really helps!